# Dragging a cell reference in intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells

I have data as follows (simplified) in two worksheets on a document:

Sheet 1 data: 
A1=1 -- B1=(Blank) -- C1=(Blank) -- D1=2 -- E1=(Blank) --  F1=(Blank) --  G1=3 ...

Sheet 2 data: 
A1='Stage Plan'!A1 -- B1='Stage Plan'!D1 -- C1='Stage Plan'!G1 ...

Essentially, I want row 1 in Sheet 2 to show all non-blank cells consecutively from row 1 in Sheet 1. The non-blank cells are spaced apart in intervals of 3 in Sheet 1.

When I attempt to drag the formula across on Sheet 2, the formula doesn't find the cells from Sheet 1 at the interval I require.

The data in Sheet 1 will be constantly changing, so I need it to update automatically on Sheet 2.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula -

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,(COLUMN(Sheet1!A1)-1)*3)`